# Apply styles to all but first type of element with class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <access type="full">
        <span class="tab">TabOne</span>
    <access>
    <access type="full">
        <span class="tab">TabTwo</span>
    <access>
    <access type="full">
        <span class="tab">TabThree</span>
    <access>
    <access type="full">
        <span class="tab">TabFour</span>
    <access>
</div>
```

I'd like to apply a rule of `margin: 0 0 0 20px;` to all but the first `tab`. I've been messing with different things like:

`.tab + .tab`

`.tabs .tab:not(:first)`

`.tabs:not(:first)`

But haven't gotten anything to work. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML structure looks little bit strange and from my understanding you have to close your `<access></access>` tag.

So, it should looks like:

```
<access type="full">
    <span class="tab">TabOne</span>
</access>
```

and so on.

Then you will be able to apply some CSS like this:

```
.tab {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

access:first-child .tab {
 margin: 0;
}
```

Also, I would like to denote, that `span` is [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) HTML element by default, and you will not able to apply `margin` to it. To make it work, you should override default behavior with `display: block` to make it act as [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element.